# How do derive the expected prediction error for OLS?

Tags: variance, least-squares, expected-value

At the end of section 3.2.2 of Elements of Statistical Learning,
it shows the following:

[image]

I am having a hard time deriving this. This is what I have so far:
\begin{align}
    E[(Y_0 - \hat{f}(x_0))^2]  
    = E[Y_0^2 + \hat{f}(x_0)^2 - 2Y_0\hat{f}(x_0)] \\
    = E[Y_0^2] + E[\hat{f}(x_0)^2] - 2E[Y_0\hat{f}(x_0)] \\
    = E[f(x_0)^2 + \epsilon_0^2 + 2f(x_0)\epsilon_0] + E[(x_0\hat{\beta})^2] - 2E[(f(x_0) + \epsilon_0)x_0\hat{\beta}] \\
    = E[f(x_0)^2] + E[\epsilon_0^2] + 2f(x_0)E[\epsilon_0] + E[(x_0\hat{\beta})^2] - 2f(x_0)E[x_0\hat{\beta}] - 2E[ \epsilon_0x_0\hat{\beta}] \\
    = E[f(x_0)^2] + E[\epsilon_0^2] + E[(x_0\hat{\beta})^2] - 2f(x_0)E[x_0\hat{\beta}] - 2E[ \epsilon_0x_0\hat{\beta}] && \text{assume } E[\epsilon_0] = 0 \\
    = f(x_0)^2 + \sigma^2  + E[(x_0\hat{\beta})^2] - 2f(x_0)E[x_0\hat{\beta}] - 2E[ \epsilon_0x_0\hat{\beta}] && E[\epsilon^2] = \sigma^2\\
\end{align}

I don't see how this simplifies, and I think I may have taken a wrong path. Is this the correct approach, and if so, how do I simplify?

Comment: The first equality of $(3.22)$ follows immediately from the assumed independence of $\varepsilon_0$ (implied by the phrase "new response") and the errors involved in $\tilde\beta.$  The second equality is just the definition of MSE.

Comment: @whuber Ah I see, I can simplify my last expression to the given based on the independence because the last term, $E[\epsilon_0 x_0 \hat{\beta}] = E[\epsilon_0] E[x_0\hat{\beta}] = 0$. But it seems I would still have to go through the same series of steps to arrive at the conclusion. By "immediate," do you mean that there's a much shorter way than what I did to arrive at the conclusion?

Comment: Yes: it's what you quoted.  No algebra is needed beyond recognizing that the variance of a sum of independent variables it is the sum of their individual variances.  The book hasn't left out any steps.

Comment: @whuber I do understand the variance of a sum of independent RVs is the sum of their individual variances. But the original expectation, $E[(Y_0 - \hat{f}(x_0))^2]$ isn't in the form of a variance? In other words I am not seeing the "variance of a sum of variables" in the initial equation.

Comment: The expectation of this argument is zero, whence its variance is the expectation of its square.

Comment: @whuber Got it. Leaving this here for myself and in case others might have the same question in the future

$$
E[Y_0 - \hat{f}(x_0)] = E[Y_0] - E[\hat{f}(x_0)] \\
= E[f(x_0)] - E[\hat{f}(x_0)] = 0  \ \ \ \text{assuming unbiased estimator} \\
$$
So we have
$$
var(Y_0 - \hat{f}(x_0)) = E[(Y_0 - \hat{f}(x_0))^2] \\
= var(Y_0) + var(\hat{f}(x_0))
$$
$var(Y_0) = \sigma^2$, and $var(\hat{f}(x_0)) = E[(\hat{f}(x_0) - f(x_0))^2]$